# How to draw a vector diagram with TikZ datavisualization?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I decided to use `TikZ datavisualization` because of many possibilities:

- adjustments for axes, grid, legend and ticks
- automatic placement of labels and legend
- automatic drawing of data value sets
- style sheet `vary dashing`: Possibility to differ a set of vectors, even if one using black-white printing.

Here my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\newcommand\U[1]{\underline U_{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes={clean, end labels},
                       all axes = {ticks = {major at = 0}},
                       x axis = {label = Re},
                       y axis = {label = Im},
                       visualize as line/.list = {U_R, I, U_L, U_C, U},
                       style sheet = vary dashing,
                       I = {label in legend = {text = $\underline I$}},
                       U_R = {label in legend = {text = $\U{R}$}},
                       U_L = {label in legend = {text = $\U{L}$}},
                       U_C = {label in legend = {text = $\U{C}$}},
                       U = {label in legend = {text = $\U{}$}}
                      ]
    data[set = U_R] {
                     x, y
                     0, 0
                     2, 0
                    }
    data[set = I] {
                   x, y
                   0, 0
                   4, 0
                  }
    data[set = U_L] {
                     x, y
                     2, 0
                     2, 2
                    }
    data[set = U_C] {
                     x,   y
                     2.1, 2
                     2.1, 1
                    }
data[set = U] {
               x, y
               0, 0
               2, 1
              };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: result]

I wish:

1. Each vector should ends (as far as possible automatically) with an arrow tip.
2. Angle for the vector `U`. Something like this (picture from above, modified with a graphic program):

[image: resault1]

Of course one can use something like (`TikZ & PGF` manual page 44):

[image: result2]

or (`TikZ & PGF` manual page 361):

[image: result3]

But in both cases one have a lot of "hand work" and less possibilities for adjustments.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With use of TikZ libraries `angles` and `quotes` (for second sub-question) and added option `every visualizer/.style={->},` for the first sub-question, your MWE gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,datavisualization.formats.functions,quotes}
\newcommand\U[1]{\underline U_{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes={clean, end labels},
                       all axes = {ticks = {major at = 0}},
                       x axis = {label = Re},
                       y axis = {label = Im},
                       visualize as line/.list = {U_R, I, U_L, U_C, U},
                       style sheet = vary dashing,
                       I = {label in legend = {text = $\underline I$}},
                       U_R = {label in legend = {text = $\U{R}$}},
                       U_L = {label in legend = {text = $\U{L}$}},
                       U_C = {label in legend = {text = $\U{C}$}},
                       U = {label in legend = {text = $\U{}$}},
                       every visualizer/.style={->}, % <-- added fo first sub-question
                      ]
    data[set = U_R] {
                     x, y
                     0, 0
                     2, 0
                    }
    data[set = I] {
                   x, y
                   0, 0
                   4, 0
                  }
    data[set = U_L] {
                     x, y
                     2, 0
                     2, 2
                    }
    data[set = U_C] {
                     x,   y
                     2.1, 2
                     2.1, 1
                    }
data[set = U] {
               x, y
               0, 0
               2, 1
              };
% added for second sub-question
\coordinate (A) at (2.5,1.5);
\coordinate (B) at (2.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
\pic [draw, angle radius=11 mm, "$\phi$"] {angle = B--C--A};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T. and @Zarko! Thank you both for the wonderful solution!